# How can I custom react components with TS Generics?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I want to create a custom component with generics. But how I do it ?

Blogs.tsx

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { NativeStackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Card from '../components/Card';
import { IStack } from '../navigation/NavBar';
import Blog from './Blog';

  type NavProp = NativeStackScreenProps<IStack, 'Blogs'>

const Blogs = ({ navigation }: NavProp) => {

  const handleNavigate = (name: string) => {
    navigation.navigate('Blog', { name });
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <ScrollView>
        <Blog items={['ASASD', 'asdasdsda', 'asdsda']}  onPress={(name) => console.log('PRESS')} />
        <Blog items={[
          {
            name: 'John',
            age: 20
          },
          {
            name: 'Hanna',
            age: 22
          }
        ]}  onPress={(name) => console.log('PRESS')} />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  )
};

export default Blogs;
```

Blog.tsx

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useMemo, useReducer, useState, useRef, useDebugValue, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';
import { Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

type TBlog<T> = {
  items: T[],
  onPress: (name: T) => void;
}

const Blog = <T extends { }>({ items, onPress }: TBlog<T>) => {
  
  return (
    <View>
        {
          items.map((el, i) => (
            <Pressable key={i} onPress={() => onPress(el)}>
              <Text>{el?.name ? el.name : el}</Text>
            </Pressable>
          ))
        }
    </View>
  )
};

export default Blog;
```

So if I use this component then its only for objects, but not for strings. So how can I make it for this type what I want in this blog ?

Comment: when you say `T extends { }` you are explicitly restricting the generic to be an object type. You should not do that if you want it to be any type

Comment: What sould I do then ?

Comment: `T extends any` (or just `T,` the comma is because it's tsx and will see `<T>` as JSX)